# Using the same codebase can a Flutter Windows desktop app be built for MacOS

Tags: flutter

I've written a desktop app for Windows using Flutter on a windows machine.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/desktop

The documentation above states it must be built on the target platform. Does this mean I can clone the same codebase on macOS and create a build compatible with Mac? Or will I have to create a new project specifically for Mac and transfer the code

Answer (score 0):

yes, if your project have directories named by macos, just run flutter run on your platform target and this works, if doesn't have, just run in your terminal this code under and works to all plataforms.

```bash
flutter create .
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build on macOS I realized the issue was I'm building on a Mac with the new M1 chip. This requires me to run:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

before building in order to support the chip's new architecture. Hope this helps and goodluck